# Browser Inconsistencies with jQuery :empty. How do I get around this?

Tags: jquery

Firefox and Internet Explorer seem to handle the :empty modifier in jQuery differently.

IE funnily enough, works how I want it to, but Firefox seems to count white space as an actual character. This therefore renders using :empty completely useless, as I can't see if a DIV is empty or not.

I basically have a set of DIV's with a class of item on them. I want to remove all DIV's with no content inside them, though white space may be present. I tried using this:

`$(".item:empty").remove();`

However, running a check on the length of the string reveals that Firefox still thinks that in an empty DIV there are characters...even though it's just white space.

So I tried trimming it too:

`if($.trim($(".item").text()) == "") {
$(".item").remove();
}`

However, the trim function doesn't seem to have an effect on this. What now??

My markup is like so:

`<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item">hello 3</div>`

I want to get rid of all DIV's with nothing in them.

Any ideas?

Many thanks,
Michael.

Answer (score 1):

It's okay now.

What I did in the end was this:

`$(".item").each(function(myItem){
        var myItem = jQuery.trim($(this).text());
        if(myItem.length == 0) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    })`

Hope it helps someone in future.

Comment: Yeah, .text() didn't work in your first example because it pulls the combined text of **all** elements with class "item", so if there were any .item on the page with text in it your comparison would fail.  Glad you worked it out.